# global variable is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

```
Dictionary<string, string> propertyCompany = new Dictionary<string, string>();//gloabal variable

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!isPostBack){
      propertyCompany .add("a","1"); 
      propertyCompany .add("b","2");
      propertyCompany .add("c","3");
   }
}

protected void btnGetProperty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string a=propertyCompany["a"];//error this key is not exist
     //propertyCompany is null
}
```

when define a `propertyCompany` and fill in `form_load`. in on click button `propertyCompany` is null!?

i use a `static` but i does not understand sometime say error is null.

Comment: `null` or just empty? Do you really mean the three items you added in `Page_Load` are not present in `btnGetProperty_Click`?

Comment: @Graham Unless there's code we don't see that's affecting things, I'm pretty sure it's "no data" rather than `null`. The initializer will be added to the beginning of the constructor, and will be run on every page load.

Comment: @dlev: yes, I'm sure that's the case, I was just trying to prompt the OP to examine things a bit more thoroughly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each request creates new page object, therefore you cannot use in second request (bnt click) dictionary you have created in first request (load without postback)

Remove test for postback for quick fix.

Other fix posibilities:
* store dictionary in viewstate.

Comment: i want use this variable in test

Comment: so just remove if(!isPostBack){ condition

Answer (score 1):

Every variable defined in a class inheriting `Web.UI.Page` will be destroyed at the end of the Page-Lifecycle, hence it will be `null` in a Postback if you don't reinitialize it.

One way to persist it across postbacks is to store it in a [Session-variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx).

You will find a complete list of all options on how to persist variables across postbacks here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

- Application
- Cookies
- Form Post / Hidden Form Field
- QueryString
- Session
- New State Containers in ASP.NET
- Cache
- Context
- ViewState
- Web.config and Machine.config Files
  Conclusion

It's in the nature of [HTTP-protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP_session_state) that it is **stateless**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your title should be "global variable does not have the data I want." The dictionary will be *constructed* each time the page is loaded (postback or otherwise), but because of this line:

```
if(!isPostBack) {
}
```

it won't have the data you want on a button click.

In order to notify the page of the click, a post back *is* performed, so saying `!isPostBack` (which I'm assuming is set somewhere via `Page.IsPostBack`) is also saying "if I haven't clicked the button", which is of course not what you want.

In order to get the functionality you want, you should either move the population of the dictionary out of that if block, or else have an else condition that also populates it with data you want.

Another alternative to using the class variable is to store the data in another location. Options include `ViewState`, `Session`, `Application` (if it really is application-wide data), the `Cache`, and some others as well. It's not clear exactly what the dictionary is doing, so it's hard to say which location would be most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get your dictionary to live between requests is to declare it static, or in viewstate as was suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing the items in propertyCompany in the button click event? If you are doing that incorrectly, that is more likely the issue.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    Dictionary<string, string> propertyCompany;//gloabal variable

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   propertyCompany = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   if(!isPostBack){
      propertyCompany .add("a","1"); 
      propertyCompany .add("b","2");
      propertyCompany .add("c","3");
   }
}
```

protected void btnGetProperty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //propertyCompany is null
}